# Why is memory consumption getting larger and larger in a foreach cycle?

Tags: php, memory-consumption

I have a big amount of data which is being processing using CLI.

In the scipt the data goes through a foreach cycle.

But on every iteration the memory consumption is getting larger and larger.

Why is this happening? Every var is getting reassigned in the loop, so there must not be memory leaks. Although I tried to set a var null on the end of every iteration, it didn't help.

In the loop I use objects (ActiveRecord) and work with a DB.

At the beginning the script works really fast (about 10 iterations per second), by the end its performance is less than 1 iteration per second.

Thanks.

Comment: We can't be expected to tell you why your code is increasing memory usage if we can't see the code.

Comment: Are we mindreaders, we're supposed to be able to figure this out without seeing a single line of code?

Comment: One of the possibilities is a BUG in PHP or in your looping. Could you post some code to check it for problems

Comment: I'd say that it's perfectly normal that a program consumes more memory the longer it loops..

Comment: @Zar Yeah you have a point in that..

Comment: If I remember correctly, the implementation of PHPs foreach might be the bad guy.

As far as I remember, the implementation allocates its own variables for internal use, which means that every time you step to the next array item, a new local variable will be allocated. The last temporary variable will also remain after the foreach block is finished.

Comment: Oh guys thanks for downvoting. I just wanted to talk about if it's ok that loop is consuming more and more memory on every iteration. As Zar said, it's normal. But I don't get why. I'd show the code, but it has too much related classes.

Comment: @nallerooth thank you! I'll try to use `for` instead of `foreach`.

Comment: I tried to write a much more informative answer than that, but the question got locked before I could finish. =/

Answer (score 1):

I suppose your answer can be found [here](http://www.php.net/manual/pl/features.gc.performance-considerations.php) in docu - garbage collector is fired from time to time, not at every single iteration.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but even after a 1000th iteration memory consumption is only getting larger.

Comment: It can be a bug in PHP, please read that docu about garbage collection. I remember that in older versions of PHP there was a problem with that, I'm not sure if it is already fixed.